Actionscript 3 : Draw movieclip as bitmap after scaling movieclip containing vectors?
Trying to draw a scaled movieclip containing vectors as a bitmap after the movieclip has been scaled, and struggling to get a sharp, clear bitmap.
Basically, have a movieclip and want to attach it to the stage, increase in scale, then draw as bitmap at its NEW increased scale to keep the sharpness while enabling faster animation on a device (since vectors animate slower)
At the moment have the following code which only produces a pixelated result:
var container:MovieClip = new MovieClip;
this.addChild(container);

var newMc:MovieClip = new myMc();           
newMc.scaleX = newMc.scaleY = 1.5;
newMc.x = 0;
newMc.y = 0;

container.addChild(newMc);

var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(container.width, container.height);      
bitmapData.draw(container);

var newBitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
this.addChild(newBitmap);

this.removeChild(container);

Any help appreciated!

Try this one instead of draw(...): https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html#drawWithQuality()

Drawn Movieclip is still coming out pixelated if scaling down before drawing. Same with using scale transform matrix... Essentially trying to scale a vector movieclip to the right size THEN draw it as a bitmap so its as sharp. Any ideas how to do this in code?

Did you use the right quality argument?

Yes : bitmapData.drawWithQuality(container, null, null, null, null, true, StageQuality.BEST);

Been on this for a day now trying every way can think of... with no luck. Seems pretty obvious in theory. Add a movieclip, scale it down, then bitmap trace it but it ends up pixelated every time :(

Do you experience the same thing with the code above and drawwithquality?

No. I worked with BitmapData 15 to 10 years ago and don't think I have ever encountered any pixelization problems that couldn't be solved by exact positioning and/or sizing and/or figuring out arguments to produce the best results. BTW, if you set the current stage quality to the best, does the bitmap still stay pixelized? Because I just had an idea that bitmap could be fine itself, but if it is drawn under the poor global quality setting, it loses its smoothness and quality nonetheless.

Still having issues for some reason. Besides, android device is taking way too long to draw bitmaps at runtime so decided on producing the bitmaps at a large scale then preloading and scaling them instead...regarding this, is there any way to get a bitmap as a child inside a moveclip then attach it to the stage? i.e. var myBitmap:Bitmap = myMc.getChildAt(0) as Bitmap.   addChild(myBitmap). - this method is currently producing errors.

If I remember correctly, raster images you put manually become Shapes during runtime (with bitmap fill). If you want to work with Bitmap instance specifically, you need to assign a new class to your image, say, MyImage and then instantiate it as new MyImage. It subclasses either Bitmap or BitmapData, I don't remember which one exactly but I believe you can figure that one out.

This code is sizing the movieclip traced as a bitmap correctly, but its still pixelated                          stage.quality = StageQuality.BEST;
var bitmapWidth:Number = mc.width;
var bitmapHeight:Number = mc.height; 
   
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(bitmapWidth, bitmapHeight, 

true);
var matrix:Matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.scale(mc.scaleX, mc.scaleY);
bitmapData.drawWithQuality(mc, matrix, null, null, null, true, StageQuality.BEST);
bitmapData.draw(mc);
var bitmap:Bitmap = new Bitmap(bitmapData);
this.addChild(bitmap);

Ahem. You draw with quality and then draw it over without quality.

What would that code look like, was unaware you could draw twice?

You draw twice. Which means, the second one (without quality) draws over the first one (with quality), which means the first one is completely wasted, both in terms of result and spent resources (time and CPU).

But the first one is blurry/pixelated when bitmap matrix is used... even if we use drawwithquality. The only workaround found is do draw the bitmap at a larger scale then scale down the bitmap... working with a vector graphic of around 182 x 182 pixels here, but it still shouldnt be pixelated when drawn as a bitmap
